# Hide label from configuration screen vscode api

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

Recently I am developing vscode extension in which I don't want setting label above checkbox as shown in screenshot.
[vscode extension configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAiBU.png)

```
configuration": {
  "title": "test",
  "properties": {
    "test.results": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "description": "Get only failed results",
      "default": true,
      "order": 0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please do provide a minimal set of reproducible code, as well as avoiding links to extern pages, thanks.

Comment: Links to external pages are totally ok, provided there's a copy of the essential part in the posting or these links otherwise add context/info to the post.